# "x" hides member of supertype 'Enum' and needs to 'override' modifier - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

I'm trying to use enum classes in Kotlin with one of my projects. The problem is I can't assign values to enum class. It says

> "name" hides member of supertype 'Enum' and needs to 'override'
>   modifier.

I'm out of solutions. What should I do ?

Here is my enum class:

```
enum class Sigorta (val name: String) {
    TRAFIK("Trafik Sigortası"),
    KASKO("Kasko Sigortası"),
    FERDI("Ferdi Kaza Sigortası"),
    SEYAHAT("Seyahat Sigortası"),
    SAGLIK("Sağlık Sigortası"),
    KONUT("Konut Sigortası"),
    DASK("Dask Sigortası");
}
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
Sigorta.TRAFIK.name // "Trafik Sigortası"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use `name`, it's already defined in the Enum class. Rename your property, like this

```
enum class Sigorta (val value: String) {
    TRAFIK("Trafik Sigortası"),
    KASKO("Kasko Sigortası"),
    FERDI("Ferdi Kaza Sigortası"),
    SEYAHAT("Seyahat Sigortası"),
    SAGLIK("Sağlık Sigortası"),
    KONUT("Konut Sigortası"),
    DASK("Dask Sigortası");
}
```

then use

```
Sigorta.TRAFIK.value
```